# JQuery simple tab program does not show nested Div Tag

Tags: jquery

This code shows the primary div tag elements fine but ignores or does not recognize CSS and HTML in a child div tag.

I can get this code to open multiple divs but not the divs nested inside the first level of divs.  6 hours later I am hoping for outside help.

Here is the code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            #tabs {
                margin:20 px 0;
            }

            #tabs ul {
                float: center;
                background: #003333;
                height:25px;
                width: 500px;
                padding-top: 4px;
            }  

            #tabs ul li {
                float: left;
                margin-left: 2em;
            }

            #tabs ul li a {
                text-decoration:none;
                color:#FFFFFF;
                font-weight:bold;
            }

            #tabs ul li.active {
                background-color:#669999;
            }

            #tabs div {
                position:absolute;
                width:500px;
                height:500px;
                padding:20px;
                margin-top:2px;
            }

            #tab1 {
                background-color:green;
            }

            #tab2 {
                background-color:red;
            }

            #blueBox {
                float:left;
                width:100px;
                height:100px;
                background-color:yellow;
                margin-left:5px;
                margin-top:150px;
            }
        </style>

        <script src="js/jquery-1.4.2.js" type="text/javascript" /></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#tabs div').hide();
                $('#tabs div:first').fadeIn('slow');
                $('#tabs ul li:first').addClass('active');
                $('#tabs ul li a').click(function() {
                $('#tabs ul li').removeClass('active');
                $(this).parent().addClass('active');
                var selectedTab=$(this).attr('href');
                $('#tabs div').fadeOut('slow');
                $(selectedTab).fadeIn('slow');
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href='#Tab1'>Tab 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Tab2">Tab 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    <div id="Tab1">
        <p>Contents in Tab1 </p>
    </div>

<!--this next part is the part I can't get to work. The div blueBox inside the div        Tab2-->

         <div id="Tab2">
                <p>Contents in Tab2</p>
                <div id="blueBox">
                    <p>Hello</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

I believe it has something to do with not getting below the parent level to get the nested divs but haven't been able to google a solution despite an all nighter.  This is a great little code but is not practical if I can't get the nested div tags to work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only want to hide and show the direct child of `#tabs`. The other divs inside `Tab1` and `Tab2` should remain as they are. To accomplish this, use **[the direct child selector ( `>` )](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/)**.

To simply get things working change the lines that use `#tabs div` to `#tabs > div` 2 lines:

```
    $('#tabs > div').hide();                         // <== direct child selector
    $('#tabs > div').fadeOut('slow');                // <== direct child selector
```

But there are a few other improvements.

1. Changed `$('#tabs ul li').removeClass('active');` to  `$('#tabs ul li.active').removeClass('active');`, since it's a little more efficient to simple select the elements of interest with the `active` class instead of all the `li`s.
2. Include the `fadeIn` in the callback of the `fadeOut`, this'll make things appear a little smoother, since it ensures that `fadeIn` only begins once `fadeOut` ends. In fact, the whole thing looks much nicer with a `.delay()` tacked on.

.

```
$(function() {                                   // <== shorter form of doc ready
    $('#tabs > div').hide();
    $('#tabs div:first').fadeIn('slow');
    $('#tabs ul li:first').addClass('active');
    $('#tabs ul li a').click(function(){
        $('#tabs ul li.active').removeClass('active');  // <== Only what you need
        $(this).parent().addClass('active');
        var selectedTab=$(this).attr('href');
        $('#tabs > div').fadeOut('slow', function() {       // <== Use a callback
            $(selectedTab).delay(500).fadeIn('slow');          // <== add a delay
        });        
        return false;
    });
});
```

### **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/v7YgA/)**

Comment: Thanks so much. The code works as intended now with your solution. Nothing better than a simple fix.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of hiding *all* descendant `<div>` elements, only hide the first level, so change this:

```
$('#tabs div').hide();
```

To this:

```
$('#tabs > div').hide();
```

this fixes the issue since it's never hidden in the first place :)

The same applies here:

```
$('#tabs div').fadeOut('slow');
//to..
$('#tabs > div').fadeOut('slow');
```

Comment: Looks like OP is also affecting all descendants with the `fadeOut()` in addition to the `hide()`. ---- And then only the main tab `div` is faded back in but the children of the main tab remain invisible.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the great post! This was very helpful! :)

One thing I discovered, when I put the fully optimized jquery into play on my site, was that I ran into some trouble with a repeat fade-in on two of the tabs. Unfortunately, I haven't yet succeeded in discerning why I experienced this with only 2/3 tabs, but I resolved the situation by changing this:

```
$('#tabs > div').fadeOut('slow', function() { ... });
```

to this:

```
$('#tabs > div:visible').fadeOut('slow', function() { ... });
```

to avoid triggering the callback on the already-hidden div.